# add AR tag in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm wondering how to add an `AR tag` in the gazebo's world these days. But I have not found the right way to solve this problem. Or could I add an image to the world?

Thanks first!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240392/add-ar-tag-in-gazebo/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I have solved this problem.
A sample approach is to change the original model.
For example, since the model `Beer` has textures, we could change the model to AR tag.
Besides , we need to replace the `cylinder` in `model.sdf` to `box`, and change the size of the box.

---

Originally posted by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) with karma: 224 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An answer [in this thread](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8828/how-to-include-qr-in-gazebo/) introduces a repo that contains a model for a marker ID 0. Looks like that markers of other IDs still need sdf and config.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also create a Ar tag of the default ar tracking size through Blender and then export it to dae.
Here I leave a video on how to do it : [VIDEO on HOW TO](https://youtu.be/WDhIaVOUwsk)

There are 3 main steps:

1. Generate the AR tag with the [AR TRACK Package](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar), through the command:

`rosrun ar_track_alvar createMarker`.

That will generate a .png of the AR defined as you want. If you use the default size, its for a 9 cm by 9 cm panel.

2. Then you create in Blender a pannel of those dimmensions using the scale functionality and the UV texture tools.
   You then export it to dae and save the dae and the texture in a ROS package
3. You finally execute the spawning scripts and install the models where your system needs to have them in order for GAzebo to find them. Here you have all the scripts and files I used:
   [Gist of the Code Used](https://gist.github.com/RDaneelOlivav/990addc733fbeb8549c3979d5bca41b2)
   [image: image description]

Hope this was usefull.

---

Originally posted by [RDaneelOlivaw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29528/rdaneelolivaw/) with karma: 281 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-07**:
Hi, very nice video ... can we use the same for April Tags ?